# How to select data from a table row with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to extract data in a row (I only need one column actually) while pressing the input button in the row. I used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ttl_emp = $('#no_emp').text();
  var ttl_sal = $('#tl_sal').text();

  $('#wtable').on('click', 'input', function() {
    var rdata = $(this).parents('tr td:nth-child(8)').text();

    alert(rdata);
    ttl_sal = ttl_sal - c_emp_netSal;
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    $('#no_emp').text(ttl_emp - 1);
    ttl_emp = ttl_emp - 1;

    $('#tl_sal').text(ttl_sal);
  });
});
```

But failed and the console mentions undefined data. `wtable` is the id of table.

Comment: Please provide your HTML

Comment: @Jonathan i edited with parantheses

Comment: @Jonathan the html is a big code using printf . is this piece okay to evaluate ? printf("<table id='wtable'

Comment: It isn't because you're trying to extract one row(?) and your current idea of extracting it using an arbitrary `nth-child` strategy is set up for failure - i.e. what happens when that one row is not the 8-th child. You got a problem.

Comment: @Jonathan im sorry, couldnt understand that.  please elaborate. thanks.

Comment: If you are targeting a particular row, you first need to label it in whatever code generates the table with an `id` or `class`. Then use that label to target the row in javascript.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116507/discussion-between-bineesh-and-jonathan).

Comment: Do you want to select row data on button click using jquery ?

Comment: @Singh yes i want to take the data of the row or a specifit column

Comment: Check answer and if you have any confusion in this answer free to ask me.

Comment: Check answer with live demo

Answer (score 0):

As your problem you can use this code to get data from selected row in table using jquery. This is sample code and try to understand this logic, after that you can implement in your code. I hope it will be helpful for you.

**Description**
We are use `.find()` function for getting right control in table. So if you have `input` type is text, then use `.find('input[type="text"]')`

`eq()` is function to find using Index number, so if your column is first position in table then you should use `eq(0)` to get value of first column in table. This Index number condition is apply for all sibling column's.

In this code we are used `.val()` for get value from `textbox`. If you want to get text from label then you should use `.text()` .

**Logic Here**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#tableid tr').each(function(){
        var name = $(this).closest('td').find('input[type="text"]').eq(0).val();
  });
});
```

**Your code with Logic**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var ttl_emp = $('#no_emp').text();
var ttl_sal = $('#tl_sal').text();

$('#wtable tr').on('click', function() {
var rdata = $(this).find('td').eq(8).val(); // for label use val() otherwise for textbox use text() for get value

alert(rdata);
ttl_sal = ttl_sal - c_emp_netSal;
$('#no_emp').text(ttl_emp - 1);
ttl_emp = ttl_emp - 1;

$('#tl_sal').text(ttl_sal);
});
});
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kalusingh/hhswyay8/)

Comment: i just got undefined while used .val() and blank on .text() but thanks for trying for me.

Comment: what is your table id name ?

Comment: do you want to get data of column while click on table tr ?